# React, redux, saga this.props.data not available for iteration

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I spend a lot of time to figure out what should be the correct stack to develop react app today, and I come to conclusion that I need react, react-router, redux and redux-saga.

I managed to write certain stuff but now I am stuck with simple data iteration process. For example code below is going to print formatted data returned from server just fine.

```
import React from 'react';

import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { requestApiData } from "../actions";

class About extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.requestApiData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <pre>
          {JSON.stringify(this.props.data, null, 2)}
        </pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ data: state.data });

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators({ requestApiData }, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(About);
```

But when I change my render method, to something like this:

```
renderPosts() {
    return this.props.data.map((post, index) => {
      return (
        <article key={post.sys.id}>
          <h3>{post.fields.title}</h3>
          <p>{post.fields.description}</p>
        </article>
      );
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Blog Posts</h2>
        {this.renderPosts()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I will get "TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function". Which is if I am figuring this properly related to async loading.

Simple questions are how to solve this, or where to pick maybe more detailed guide so I can figure out how to do this correctly.

Comment: do `console.log(this.props.data)` to check the initial value, it should be `[]`, i think the error that you are getting is, may be because of the initial value of data is not an array.

Comment: @MayankShukla what I find with log in example where it works (stringify) it is initially empty and filled afterwards, it is [] since I am pulling it from - https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Comment: At the very least you'll need to check if `this.props.data` is an array, and if it isn't then return something like `<div>Loading...</div>` or just `null`.

Comment: @TomekRychtyk initialy it is {} but after I guess pops are filled (in working example) it is {obj,obj,obj...}

Comment: In this case you might think about converting the wrapping object to an array, for example with `Object.values(this.props.data)` and then iterate over it

Comment: @TomekRychtyk that's it, can't believe that I didn't read .map documentation properly. Thanks for the solution.